# Does follower equipment carry over difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have recently completed Normal mode and moved onto Nightmare. With this, all of my followers will have to be re-acquired.

Do equipment and spells carry over to each difficulty? I'm assuming yes, but I've also noticed that followers aren't shared with other characters.

Comment: +1, for answering a question I was going to ask about followers being shared between characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all equipment is carried over.  Not only that, but you do not have to reacquire them.

All 3 followers are available in Tristram, in Act I of Nightmare.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I was a little too absorbed with the quest line to notice :P